# BufferedWriter how to not write over text already saved?

Tags: java, file

Hi guys wondering if you can help me, i am trying to create a log file, where it saves all the variables the users has selected, so far i have got :

```
try{
         String content = (" User : " + username + "\n Print job to be printed at : " + (dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())) +"\n Copies selected : " + p +"\n Papersize selected : " + paperSize + "\n Duplex selected : " +duplex + "\n Oreination Selected : " +orienation + "\n Printer Selected : " +printer);

         //File file = new File(log);


         FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(log);
         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
         bw.write(content);
         bw.close();

         System.out.println("Logged the print job");

         } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

and this works perfectly fine, however i am wanting it next time this is called to add the data below what is already in the file, not overwriting it, is this possible ? as it would be a lot better than creating a new file each time,

Thanks

Comment: And I suggest you to use log4j, it's better than doing boilerplate code of creating file, opening etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the constructor to use the `boolean append` and send `true`.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(log, true);
```

From: [`FileWriter(File file, boolean append)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29))

Comment: Perfect ! thanks a lot :) didn't realise it was that simple !

Comment: i will do once i can in 10 minutes ! :)